# Randomly generating 4 playing cards: the textbook uses longer code?

Tags: java

Any reason this wouldn't generate randomly?
The textbook has slightly longer code.

```
int[] deck = new int[52];

        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            deck [i] = i;
        }
        String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
        String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

        int [] card = new int[4];


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int index = (int)(Math.random()*52);
            card [i] = index;
            String cardRank = ranks[index % 13];
            String cardSuit = suits[index/13];
            System.out.println("card " + i + " is a " + cardRank + " of " + cardSuit);

        }
```

Comment: its generate random for me.
warn -> u have to ace in ur rank list and % 13 :)

Comment: I think this would generate uniformly random cards. You have an extra "Ace" in your ranks array (though this doesn't matter :))

Comment: oh true. Thanks!

Comment: This could get the same card twice from "the deck". It would thus not be a deck. When you take a card out of a deck, it's supposed to be removed from the deck.